# Books on High performance Websites and scalability.

Tags: performance, scalability

Most web frameworks and "best practices" are not suitable for very high performance sites and the whitepapers from vendors out there ain't worth the paper they are printed on.

So where should someone look to find books, tutorials or other resources on this subject?

Answer (score 20):

Have a look at Cal Henderson's, 'Building Scalable Websites' by O'Reilly

[http://www.amazon.com/Building-Scalable-Web-Sites-Applications/dp/0596102356](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102356)

he's the guy behind Flickr.

Also have a look at [highscalability.com](http://highscalability.com), They have some of the architectures of the most loaded sites out there.

Comment: +1 for the mention of highscalability.com, that's a very useful resource.

Comment: Its 2018. Is Cal Henderson's, 'Building Scalable Websites' by O'Reilly still a valid source or is it outdated? :)

Answer (score 5):

You should not look at scalability as a bandaid or a one time fix.

As the usage of your application changes, your scalability requirements will change and evolve. Also, there is no silver bullet for addressing scalability. It is a mix of various approaches like caching, replication, distribution, performance tuning, hardware upgrades etc. You should choose from those based on the context of "what you want to scale" and where will you get maximum bang for the buck!

check out this link
http://sevenoct.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/scaling-applications/

which has some good information about scalability and how not to fall into traps of "sought after" scalability mantras

Answer (score 4):

I have done quite a bit of search on this.Finally boiled down to these three books.

1. [High Performance Websites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529309)
2. [Even faster websites](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596522304)
3. [The art of scalability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137030428)